# android radio group can not select the same element

Tags: android, select, radio-group

I am a fresher in android programming and little confused. My program is a simple quiz show. I have question = textview, radio group = answers and button = ok.

When user choose one element of radio group and then click ok, text question and answers should be changed in new question, I can not choose the previous element of radio group. firstly I should choose another and then I can choose previous question's element.

I used option.setchecked("false"); method but it is not still okey.

Is there anybody can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

When you click your **Ok** button you need to clear previous selections by using `RadioGroup.clearCheck()`